# Sending customer id in customer registration email opencart 3.0.2

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

I need to add customer id in customer registration email template. When I looked in mail function in `catalog/controller/mail/register.php` I could see that `$args` passing the parameters of customers details. But in that variable. there is no customer id. How can I pass customer ID too to this variable?

Answer (score 0):

In this file:

```
catalog/controller/mail/register.php
```

Find:

```
$data['firstname'] = $args[0]['firstname'];
```

Add before it:

```
$data['customer_id'] = $output;
```

In this file:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/register_alert.twig
```

Add where you want:

```
Customer ID: {{ customer_id }}
```

Then clear caches (twig cache, ocmod cache).